# Undefined index when saved to options

Tags: errors, offsets

```
$options = get_option('analytics');
if ( ! preg_match( '/^([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})$/', $options['analytics_startdate'] ) ) {
    $options['analytics_startdate'] = '2018-12-01';
}
```

Why this is throwing an error :

> Undefined index: analytics_startdate ,

though i am specifying it.

Comment: does `$options` already contain `analytics_startdate` *before* you set it here?

Comment: @Milo hi, No it was all empty , i added this only here in the above code..it is displaying the 2018-12-01 but along with this error..not sure why

Comment: because you try to use it in your `if` condition with `preg_match` before it exists.

Comment: @Milo oh yeah thank you very much ..i am confused with how to save this option . also want to make sure that user saved value is asper format

Comment: `if (!isset($options['analytics_startdate']){
  $options['analytics_startdate'] = '2018-12-01';
 }
 elseif (isset($options['analytics_startdate'])){
  if (!preg_match('/^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$/', $options['analytics_startdate'])) {
   $options['analytics_startdate'] = '2018-12-01';
 }}` will this be okay?

Comment: @Milo it seems to work now ..please make it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> though i am specifying it.

You're not actually specifying it.  You're trying to use it in your regex and THEN you specified it.

You can't use it in your "if" criteria when if it doesn't exist.  You need to check to see if it exists first.

The following would set your value if it is not set OR if it IS set and doesn't match your regex:

```
$options = get_option( 'analytics' );
if ( ! isset( $options['analytics_startdate'] ) || ! preg_match( '/^([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})$/', $options['analytics_startdate'] ) ) {
    $options['analytics_startdate'] = '2018-12-01';
}
```